# Error when trying to trim a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to trim off dangling line separators in pandas:

```
for idx, value in enumerate(df.loc[0]):
    if str(value).strip() != str(value):
        print ('AAAAAAAAAA', repr(value))
        df[idx] = df[idx].str.strip()
        print ('BBBBBBBBBB')
```

Here is what happens when I run it:

```
AAAAAAAAAA '325NYRQA82ZPP83EW9LJB3CXOZPDZM\r'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/Desktop/V/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
KeyError: 8
```

It seems that instead of calling the index number, I need to call the column name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling the index number where you need to be calling the index name. Here is how you would adjust it:

```
for idx_name, value in df.loc[0].items():
    if str(value).strip() != str(value):
        df[idx_name] = df[idx_name].str.strip()
```